# Is it a good idea to hook up composer to manage web assets in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

As you know, in Symfony2.1 php bundles and packages are managed by composer, but would be maybe a good idea to hook up the managing of web assets as well? I would really love to update Twitter Bootstrap, jQuery, jQueryUi, Underscore.js and many other libraries using the same console command i use to update the php packages.

Are there any serious downsides of doing this?

Comment: UPDATE: I ended up using Bower in my sf2 projects and so far i'm happy with it :) Thx for suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it sounds like a great idea, but I don't think it would be possible:

1. Composer is created for handling **PHP dependencies**, not for handling front-end dependencies, the twitter team has created [Bower](http://twitter.github.com/bower/) for front-end dependencies.
2. Combining those 2 great libraries is a huge task: You will need to create your own composer commands and configuration files.
3. Bower puts everything in a `components` directory. This isn't the correct dir for web assets, you will need to change this. You can't change this in the Bower config, as far as I know about Bower, which is almost equal to zero. **UPDATE** As said by @xanido, you can [configure the output directory](https://github.com/twitter/bower/tree/v0.3.0#bower-configuration) with the `directory` option as of Bower 0.3.0.

So well, you can manage web assets in Symfony2, with Bower (and maybe other programs like that), but combining those 2 isn't a good practise. Use Bower and Composer seperately can be useful, although you get another web assets directory.

Comment: You can actually specify the bower component install path now: https://github.com/twitter/bower#bower-configuration

Comment: UPDATE: 
look this https://github.com/yohang/dependency-tools
and this https://github.com/Spea/SpBowerBundle
they do what you've said